# Understanding buffer in OpenGLES android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have this vertex shader that i'm use to rotate or translate the obj depending of state values.

```
private final String vertexShader="" +
        "attribute vec4 vertex;" +
        "attribute vec4 colors;" +
        "varying vec4 vcolors;" +
        "uniform int x;" +
        "uniform vec4 translate;"+
        "uniform mat4 rotate;"+
        "void main(){" +
            "vec4 app_verte=vertex;" +
            "if(x==1){" +
            "app_verte=vertex+translate;" +
            "}else if(x==2){" +
            "app_verte=rotate*app_verte;" +
            "}" +
            "vcolors=colors;" +
            "gl_Position=app_verte;" +
        "}";
```

For the rotation i use the a matrix that using the matrix associeted is built from a float[16] array as follow:

```
|cos(angle),-sin(angle),0,0|
|sin(angle), cos(angle),0,0|
|0         ,           ,0,0|
```

Now i have different questions becouse i really hard understand. If i want to change the type of transformation i have to set the x value. Now to have a continius transformation i supposed that the vertex buffere will be the same and after a transformation the value of the buffer will be changed. Now nothing happend becouse it transform and draw with the same coordiates. i put only at first the coordinatesbuffer. There is a way to use the same buffer that is the the VRAM without put it every time and if there is not how can a pull the changed buffer to my buffer obj after the tranformation without transform the point using the array and put it into the buffer?? 
Sorry for my english and thanks to all indeed.

Comment: Difficult to get your question. Can you simplify the question? if you are asking how to transform each vertex in your vertex shader, use one more attribute float x instead of uniform x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertex buffers are designed this way so you send them to the GPU only once to reduce the traffic. You then use matrices (or other systems such as translation vector) to apply the transform in the vertex shader so you send only up to 4x4 float buffer.

IF I understand what your issue is it lies in that you use multiple systems at the same time. You have a translation vector and a matrix but you use either one or the other. So in your case you might be able to simply apply both of them in the shader as `app_verte = rotate*app_verte + translate;` or `app_verte = rotate*(app_verte + translate);` already these 2 are not the same and I am guessing that at some point you will need something like `app_verte = rotate2*(rotate1*app_verte + translate1) + translate2;` which is not solvable since the number of operations will increase over time.

So you need to chose a single system which in your case should be a matrix. Rather then sending the translation matrix you can translate the matrix on the CPU part of your application and send only that to the shader. You need to find tools to multiply the matrices and to generate translation and rotation matrix. You can make them yourself but already looking at the one you posted I am pretty sure the second last value should be `1` and not `0` (though it must be a typo since the last row contains 3 values while others contain 4).

So have a single matrix which in beginning is set to identity which corresponds to `x=0`. Then for `x=1` situation set that matrix as a translation matrix `myMatrix = generateTranslationMatrix(x, y, z)`. And for `x=2` do the same with rotation matrix `myMatrix = generateRotationMatrix(x, y, z, angle)`. Now when you need to continue the operation, to concat the two you simply multiply them, so for both you would do `myMatrix = generateTranslationMatrix(x, y, z)*generateRotationMatrix(x, y, z, angle)`. But there is no reason to keep the values separate as well so in the end you just want some methods to manipulate the state of the orientation:

```
Matrix myMatrix;

onLoad() {
    myMatrix = Matrix.identity();
}

onTurnRight(float angle) {
    myMatrix = myMatrix * generateRotationMatrix(0, 1, 0, angle);
}

onMove(float x, float y, float z) {
    myMatrix = myMatrix * generateTranslationMatrix(x, y, z);
}
```

Then you can add other methods to your code as needed but for instance if you handle touch events and when a finger moves up or down you will move forward or backwards while left and right will rotate the object then it will look something like this:

```
onFingerMoved(float x, float y) {
   const float xfactor = 0.01; // Modify to control the speed of rotation
   const float yfactor = -0.1; // Modify to control the speed of movement

   float dx = previousX - x;
   float dy = previousy - y;
   onTurnRight(dx);
   onMove(.0, .0, dy); // Assuming the Z coordinate is forward

   previousX = x; 
   previousY = y;
}
```